# Failed to connect. Error 2 unknown not implemented in docker vscode extension

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vscode-extensions, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am getting the following upon installing the docker extension on vscode:
[image: failed to connect docker]

I am using WSL Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11 and docker desktop 4.6.1 with wsl integration.
I have tried downgrading to docker desktop 4.4.4 and adding docker to sudo in wsl.

How can I connect to docker via the extension? Docker is working through the terminal on wsl.

Comment: Is the wsl integration working fine?

Comment: Yes, I am able to enter docker commands on wsl terminal through the integration with docker desktop

Comment: Did you make sure docker is running?

Comment: Yes, docker is running. I have docker desktop opened. Docker commands are working through the terminal.

Comment: Did you check to use wsl2 support from Settings->General?

Comment: Yes, it is checked.

Comment: Is your user in the docker group?

Comment: Yes it is. Thorough sudo usermod

Comment: Did you restart your system after that?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the system.

Comment: Try downgrading to Docker Desktop 4.5.1.  I was having issues with 4.6.1 on Windows 11 and downgrading resolved the issue for me.  You can download previous releases from the release notes page: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/